# Adding an ng-element dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

If I wanted to add a dynamically created ng-href to an element how can I get it to behave like a usual ng-href?

```
<a test-href="/link">Test link</a>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive("testHref", function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      var newlink = attr.dbHref + "/additional/parameters";
      attr.$set("ng-href", newlink);
    }
  };
});
```

This produces `<a test-href="/link" ng-href="/link/additional/parameters">Test link</a>`, but how can I also get the ng-href to behave as it should?

Comment: Why? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: To add additional parameters for all links on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/UnpSH/

```
app.directive("testHref", function($compile) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      var newlink = attr.dbHref + "/additional/parameters";
      attr.$set("ng-href", newlink);
      elem.removeAttr('test-href'); // prevent recursion
      $compile(elem)(scope); // compile it again
    }
  };
});
```

Not sure what you want to achieve, but you should use something like `ng-href = "/path/{{scopeVariable}}"` for dynamically changing your link.

Comment: Sweet, it was the recursion from not removing 'test-href' attribute that got me.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind ng-href to your object's dynamic Url property like `ng-href="{DynamicUrl}"`

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngHref

If you are building a directive that require to add dynamically angulerjs directives, you shall use $compile to get appropriate result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to write a custom directive to have a dynamic url for href. You could use [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) and the scope-parameter bindings.

```
<a ng-href="/path/{{dynamic_var_on_scope}}/123/?p={{var2}}"> Click Here </a>
```

Comment: how am i supposed to get that p parameter in my controller?

Comment: You need to add parameters to the $scope. You can inject the $scope to controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind a dynamic url with `href` then you can manipulate you URL in `ng-click` or `ng-mousedown` event and bind to target element.

JS:

```
var goToDetailPage = function (event, id) {
    var newState = $state.href('DetailView', {id: id});
    jQuery(event.target).attr('href',newState);
};
```

HTML:

```
<a ng-mousedown="goToDetailPage($event, id)"> Click Here </a>
```